# Send input data outside the iframe with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, input, fill

Located outside the iframe, input into, what value is sent.

iframe outside

```
<input id="a_input_id" type="text">
```

iframe within

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="special_field_link">@r.SpecialField<a>
```

Javascript Code;(iframe in working)

```
<script>
$(function(){
$(".special_field_link").click(function(){
 $("#a_input_id").val($(this).text());
});
});
</script>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnjWH.jpg

Comment: Is it the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the iframe and the parent are in the same domain, you need to use the parent document context

```
$("#a_input_id", parent.document).val($(this).text());
```